# Replacing failed RAID 1 drive on Windows Server 2008 - new drive not bootable

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, boot

I'm trying to replace a failed RAID 1 drive in Win Server 2008 R2 Foundation and am running into difficulty.

See the image from Disk Management:

[image: Disk Management]

Disk 0 is the good drive from the original RAID array, Disk 1 is a new drive.

The 71mb "OEM Partition", as you can see has 100% free space. This is a Dell server and it came with this set up already. If I right click the volume I only get "help" in the menu.

I've mirrored the RECOVERY volume which I believe contains some (seemingly fairly useless) Dell recovery software, and I've mirrored the OS volume to the new drive. I haven't bothered with DATAPART1 yet since this is only a bunch of work files - there is no software etc. here.

The mirroring seems to have worked correctly, however I would expect to be able to remove Disk 0 from the system (by removing the SATA cable) and still be able to boot from Disk 1 only. When I try this, I get "No bootable media found" during the boot process. If I go into the Windows RE (I am having to use a Windows 7 disk as all that came with the server was a Dell recovery disk) and try Startup Repair it tells me it couldn't find any Windows installations. I believe when I unplug Disk 0, Disk 1 also shows up in the boot sequence as "Non-RAID" whereas I would expect it to show up as failed or degraded, since half of the mirror is missing.

Here is the output from bcdedit:

[image: BCDEdit]

I've never delved into the hardware RAID settings so don't really know what I'm doing there, I'm hoping there'll be a way to do this in software.

What's going to be the quickest/easiest way from here to get to the point where the new disk is bootable on its own? Can I do it through software? It seems to me like I'm almost there, but I am not experienced using BCDedit etc.

The ultimate goal is to take out the 250GB drive (Disk 0) and add in a second 2TB drive, then have the 2x2TB drives running in a mirrored set.

Comment: You can use bootrec.exe to rebuild your boot sector. You should execute all four commands in the order in the article. The article refers to windows 7 but should apply to server as well.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392

Comment: I flagged this as *too broad*. You ask numerous question within your post. You clearly have no idea what you are doing. You created a software RAID on top of a RAID controller. Serverfault is not the place to explain core concepts. -- No offense intended. But you should really, really, *really* ask your IT partner for help. He may also provide that ISO you need.

Comment: Fine. Where do I ask it? I asked a similar question on StackExchange and they said move it here. Does this mean there is nowhere on StackExchange to ask this kind of question? Where can I find a summary of what is and isn't acceptable to ask?

Comment: "If your question is about:

managing the hardware or software of servers, workstations, storage or networks... Then you're in the right place!" http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic I'm sorry I didn't realise there was an exam I have to pass to prove some arbitrary level of prior knowledge before asking a question here. If I don't know what I'm doing, then set me right maybe?

Comment: "You should really, really, really ask your IT partner for help"... OK cool I'll never learn anything for myself then. Thanks for being so helpful.

Comment: **Where do I ask?** In this scale, in a forum. **Where can I find a summary of what is and isn't acceptable to ask?** The Help Center, especially [here](http://serverfault.com/help/dont-ask). **OK cool I'll never learn anything for myself then.** That implies that there is nobody else involved. But this is not really the point. The main reason I flagged it is, that the question is too broad. Strongest indicators are the numerous questions regarding different topics. Then there is the fact that you are learning on PRODUCTIVE MACHINES! That's just plain stupid!

Comment: Welcome to the realistic world of small business. Tech support is a secondary role for me and we have a small budget for such. Would you care to direct me to a previous question asking the same thing? I had a look at the previous questions and there's nothing actually relevant. I've removed the portion asking for the ISO, which leaves 2 questions: "What's the quickest way to do this? Can I do it through software?". Doesn't seem very broad to me.

Comment: Oh, you wouldn't believe how many small companies I already had to tell "Sorry, data is gone. Next time, ask us first". Yours sounds just like it is soon to become on of them.

Comment: I have multiple backups of the important server data including on another machine in the office, on an external hard drive in another location, and on iDrive online backup. Data integrity is not an issue. What is an issue is replacing the hard drive and getting it to the stage where it can boot properly. Yes I could reinstall windows and start over again but I'd really prefer not to as we have some specialist license server software which is a pain to set up.